# Switching from C to C++: looking for safe classes of primitive types

Tags: c++, exception, types

For example, in C, I had to use the following functions for the `int` type:

```
extern int add_i(int a, int b)
{
    if (a > 0 && b > 0)
    {
        // a + b <= INT_MAX    | - a
        // b <= INT_MAX - a
        assert(b <= INT_MAX - a);
    }
    else if (a < 0 && b < 0)
    {
        // a + b >= INT_MIN    | - a
        // b >= INT_MIN - a
        assert(b >= INT_MIN - a);
    }
    return a + b;
}

extern int sub_i(int a, int b)
{
    if (a > 0 && b < 0)
    {
        // Below both a and b are positive
        // a - (-b) <= INT_MAX    | + (-b)
        // a <= INT_MAX + (-b)
        assert(a <= INT_MAX + b);
    }
    else if (a < 0 && b > 0)
    {
        // (-a) - b >= INT_MIN    | + b
        // (-a) >= INT_MIN + b
        assert(a >= INT_MIN + b);
    }
    return a - b;
}

extern int mul_i(int a, int b)
{
    if ((a > 0 && b > 0) || (a < 0 && b < 0))
    {
        // a * b <= INT_MAX    | : a
        // b <= INT_MAX / a
        assert(b <= INT_MAX / a);
    }
    else
    {
        if (a < 0)
        {
            // Below both a and b are positive
            // (-a) * b >= INT_MIN    | : (-a)
            // b >= INT_MIN / (-a)
            assert(b >= INT_MIN / a);
        }
        else if (b < 0)
        {
            // Below both a and b are positive
            // a * (-b) >= INT_MIN    | : (-b)
            // a >= INT_MIN / (-b)
            assert(a >= INT_MIN / b);
        }
    }
    return a * b;
}

extern int div_i(int a, int b)
{
    assert(b != 0);
    return a / b;
}

extern int mod_i(int a, int b)
{
    assert(b != 0);
    return a % b;
}
```

Now that I'm switching to C++, I'm looking for classes that would overload the operators of the primitive types to catch all the exceptions for me.

Also, safe conversion functions between primitive types would be nice as well:

```
extern unsigned i_2_u(int i)
{
    assert(i >= 0);
    return (unsigned) i;
}

extern int u_2_i(unsigned u)
{
    assert(u <= INT_MAX);
    return (int) u;
}
```

Some other things would also be very nice:

- Implementation of predefined types, such as `size_t`
- A macro to define a simple range type of your own, e.g.

`#define new_type(name, underlying_primitive_type, min_value, max_value) ...`
`new_type(WeekDayNumber, int, 1, 7)`

Has someone made such a thing in C++? Thanks!

Comment: You can't overload the operators for built in types in C++.

Comment: Looks like you want a template.

Comment: @101010 Oh, sorry, I didn't know that. Is there a work-around? Like defining a class with only one variable and then overloading the operators of THAT class?

Comment: @Xis88 yes, you can do it. It will compile into the same code as if you overloaded operators for primitive types.

Comment: I think you may need to think of a language other than C++, then... Or, at least, of a specialized compiler extension that will do the extra checks you desire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm looking for classes that would overload the operators of the primitive types

There are no such classes in the standard library, but they can be implemented in C++. You can create a class with a single data member and implement operator overloads for it.

Alternatively, you can keep using the C functions that you already have.

> Some other things would also be very nice:
>
> Implementation of predefined types, such as size_t
>
> A macro to define a simple range type of your own, e.g.

You can make a class template and parametrize the members based on type argument. You can use [numeric_limits](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits) for the templated limit detection.

Your C functions can also be transformed into function templates.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can't overload operator for built-in type in C++, as it is required by the language that an overloaded operator has at least one parameter of user defined type. That's you can't do something like this:

```
int operator+(int a, int b) {
  // ...
  return a + b;
}
```

You could however write a class (e.g., `class Number`) and overload the specific operators (e.g., `operator+`, `operator*`) for `Number` objects.

e.g.,:

```
template<typename T>
struct Number {
  T n;
};

template<typename T>
Number<T> operator+(Number<T> const &a, Number<T> const &b) {
  if (a.n > 0 && b.n > 0) assert(b.n <= std::numeric_limits<T>::max() - a.n);
  else if (a < 0 && b < 0) assert(b.n >= std::numeric_limits<T>::min() - a.n);

  Number<T> res;
  res.n = a + b;

  return res;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could refactor to use a complement of template arguments and the standard template std::numeric_limits<>.

This way you'd get complete coverage of all integer types while only expressing logic once.

You'll also find that in a release build, the entire function will be inlined if the compiler knows the values at the call site.

I have refactored sub_i for you:

```
#include <limits>
#include <cassert>


template<class IntType>
IntType sub(IntType a, IntType b)
{
    if (a > 0 && b < 0)
    {
        // Below both a and b are positive
        // a - (-b) <= INT_MAX    | + (-b)
        // a <= INT_MAX + (-b)
        assert(a <= std::numeric_limits<IntType>::max() + b);
    }
    else if (a < 0 && b > 0)
    {
        // (-a) - b >= INT_MIN    | + b
        // (-a) >= INT_MIN + b
        assert(a >= std::numeric_limits<IntType>::min() + b);
    }
    return a - b;
}

int main()
{
  int a = 65;
  int b = 74;

    return sub(a, b);
}
```

Safe conversion of primitive types can be achived by using brace initialisation. This will cause a compiler warning if the conversion is a narrowing conversion:

example:

```
int x = 54;
short y = { x };
```

causes:

```
32 : warning: narrowing conversion of 'x' from 'int' to 'short int' inside { } [-Wnarrowing]
short y = { x };
^
```

For completeness, here's the infrastructure for the value ranges you want:

```
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
struct value_range_iterator

{
    using value_type = T;

    constexpr value_range_iterator(T v) : _v(v) {}

    constexpr value_type operator*() const noexcept {
        return _v;
    }

    constexpr value_range_iterator& operator++() noexcept {
        ++_v;
        return *this;
    }

    constexpr bool operator==(const value_range_iterator& r) const noexcept {
        return _v == r._v;
    }

    constexpr bool operator!=(const value_range_iterator& r) const noexcept {
        return _v != r._v;
    }

    T _v;
};

namespace detail {
    template<class T>
    struct value_range
    {
        constexpr value_range(T b, T e) : _begin(b), _end(e) {}

        constexpr auto begin() const {
            return value_range_iterator<T>(_begin);
        }

        constexpr auto end() const {
            return value_range_iterator<T>(_end);
        }

        T _begin, _end;
    };
}

template<class T>
auto inclusive_value_range(T from, T to)
{
    return detail::value_range<T>(from, to+1);
}

int main()
{
    for(auto i : inclusive_value_range(1, 5))
    {
        std::cout << i << ", ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

expected results:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5,
```

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, there is no standard wrapper for this purpose. However, it may be interesting to implement it.

There is example for generic wrapper and `operator+` implementation:

```
#include <limits>
#include <cassert>    
#include <iostream>


template <typename UnsafeType> class SafeWrapper
{
private:
    UnsafeType m_data;

public: 

    SafeWrapper(const UnsafeType& from) : m_data(from) {}     // implicitly create from unsafe type
    operator UnsafeType() const        { return m_data; }     // implicitly convert to unsafe type

    template <typename AnotherType>
    SafeWrapper operator+(const AnotherType& right) const
    {
        assert(m_data <= std::numeric_limits<UnsafeType>::max() - right);
        return SafeWrapper<UnsafeType>(m_data + right);
    }
};

int main()
{
    SafeWrapper<int> i = 2100000000;
    std::cout << i + 1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << i + i << std::endl;
}
```

Compilation and output:

```
sh-4.3$ g++ -std=c++11 -o main *.cpp                                                                                                                                       
sh-4.3$ main                                                                                                                                                               
2100000001                                                                                                                                                                 
main: main.cpp:22: SafeWrapper<UnsafeType> SafeWrapper<UnsafeType>::operator+(const AnotherType&) const [with AnotherType = SafeWrapper<int>; UnsafeType = int]: Assertion 
`m_data <= std::numeric_limits<UnsafeType>::max() - right' failed.                                                                                                         
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I think, it's easy to implement other operators this way.